# Plant growing below flat roof

Tags: roof, building

My neighbours have a plant growing out the wall where it meets the roof (flat roof).  I mentioned it to them years ago and they must have pulled it out but it’s back and I’m worried it’s growing along inside of roof and could destroy my side of the semi detached building.  Any help on how to deal with it or report it.    Is it harmful. It looks like a creeping green leafy plant but I’ve not seen it growing that much to get Japanese knot wood (unless the growing is within the walls) [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to DIY. To identify the plant, please add a close-up picture of the leaves. Can you find where it is rooted or where it enters? It might be going up in the wall entering through vent gaps, behind siding etc... In any case this must be resolved as it can mechanically damage walls, drains, gutters and promote rain water ingress and invite rodents.

Answer (score 1):

Plant roots will do damage to even brickwork, compromising the mortar or even cracking bricks. That looks to be stucco and it would not be as tough.

I would not want anything growing out of my walls.

I used to like the way ivy looked until purchasing a house with an ivy covered wall. The brickwork was in such bad shape we removed the brick and resided.

I would get a woody plant herbicide and spray the plant before permanent damage to the siding and possibly roofing is done.

Comment: OP will likely have to find the point of entry, as some plants are hardy enough to grow back.

Comment: I use a product called crossbow (or similar they changed the name) put this on the leaves in the growing season and it is taken down to the roots it kills black berries and as an Oregon resident I can tell you these are tough to kill.